# How to send sms to multiple contacts and get the result code for each of them in android

Tags: android, sms

Below link tells how to send sms to single contact and get resultcode[link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)

but How to send sms to multiple contacts and get the result code for each of them  in android